# Approach to using TypeScript descriptor files, such as Knockout.d.ts

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I have just been looking over some of the examples from

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

And noticed that some of the libraries in there were not as easy to just pick up and use as I thought, but this is probably because I am still a newcomer to the TypeScript show.

So the first thing that struck me as off (using Knockout as the example here), none of it is included within a module, which I dont really think is a major issue probably more a design decision by whoever made it, but it seemed like it would make more sense (possibly because I tend to do more C# than other languages) because it would be self contained and easier to include other plugins under the namespace:

`i.e Knockout.ObservableString();`

Anyway the 2nd point is more about how to use these implementations in real world scenarios, as normally I would do something like:

```
function SomeClass() {
    var self = this;

    self.SomeObservable = ko.observable("default-value");
}
```

Now I was expecting to do something like this:

```
/// The Ref
interface ISomeClass {
    SomeObservable: KnockoutObservableString;
}

class SomeClass implements ISomeClass {
    // What goes here?
}
```

Now pretend for a minute that there is some logical reason to make my POJO (I guess it should be called a POTO now though) an interface then implement it, as normally I wouldn't bother putting an interface on anything which has 0 behaviour.

Now in the above example the interface would be fine as there is a `KnockoutObservableString` interface, however I couldn't find an implementation, so am I not meant to be using that interface or should I be making my own implementations?

I could do with someone to just point me in the direction and answer:

```
A) Why it wasn't written as a module?
B) How do you actually use the descriptors properly?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The descriptors are used to apply types to an existing javascript library, but they don't redefine the library interface or cause anything to change when compiling to javascript.  I think this comes into play with both of your questions:

A) The knockout descriptor cannot be defined in a module because knockout defines ko as a global variable.  Suppose `ko` had been defined in a `Knockout` module within the descriptor.  Then the generated javascript that is generated by typescript would be something like `SomeObservable = Knockout.ko.observable("default-value")`, which is not valid.

B) For the most part, invoking knockout within typescript will look the same as javascript.  So you could do something like this:

```
class SomeClass implements ISomeClass {
    SomeObservable = ko.observable("default-value");
}
```

The descriptor file defines several overloads for ko.observable, and the one that takes a string argument returns a KnockoutObservableString.  So the implementation and use of ko doesn't really change much... the only thing the descriptor really gives you is a little more type safety.

Answer (score 0):

Right I think I may have a bit more of an idea about all this...

Now to answer the B) I think you are supposed to use them by including them which would be like:

`declare var ko: KnockoutStatic`

However if you look at the bottom of the knockout descriptor its already done for you, and then I think you are meant to use the interfaces for the interfaces you make, then the ko.xxx for your actual implementations, such as below:

```
/// <reference path="knockout.d.ts" />

interface IPerson
{
    Forename: KnockoutObservableString;
    Surname: KnockoutObservableString;
}

class Person implements IPerson
{
    Forename = new ko.observable("");
    Surname = new ko.observable("");
}
```

Although Rubymine 5 seems to think that the assignment to Forename and Surname is invalid, but I dont know why visual studio seems to think its ok.

So I hope someone else can verify im on the right track here.

Comment: You don't need to instantiate a `new` ko.observable... `Forename = ko.observable("");` should do what you want.